# Как задать размер временной директории для apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService?

Tags: java, apache, activemq

При запуске приложения получаю ERROR:

> 2017-08-09 13:21:58.073 ERROR 6317 --- [)-193.***.*.*]
>   o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Temporary Store limit is
>   51200 mb, whilst the temporary data directory:
>   /Users/pavel/GitHub/app.ru/activemq-data/localhost/tmp_storage only
>   has 40858 mb of usable space

Почему размер временной директории `tmp_storage` только `40858 mb`? Это значение по умолчанию? Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне увеличить это значение?

Проект на `SpringBoot` использует:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Все это живет на Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем `activeMQ.xml` у вас будет следующая конфигурация

```
<systemUsage>
   <systemUsage>
      ....
      <tempUsage>
         <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
      </tempUsage>
   </systemUsage>
</systemUsage>
```

Вы должны указать значение в пределах доступного места на диске. Поскольку ошибка явно указывает на то, что ваше свободное пространство равно 40858 MB, вы должны указать меньшее значение.

Вы можете установить, к примеру `<tempUsage limit="30 gb"/>`